# Word for discrimination based on familial background

Tags: single-word-requests

In a household where someone lives with his step-parent and family, how would you describe discrimination based on that person coming from a different family and surname? Best I can describe it is just discriminatory behavior but I'm hoping there's a specific word for it.

Comment: I suppose it's nepotism, but I'd consider that too hypernymic to be a reasonable answer.

Comment: He’s the *red-headed stepchild*.

Comment: I don't know of a specific word - you would have to say something like "They never quite accepted him as one of the family".